# Ember component sendAction() not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

i have been struggling with this for the past few hours, i am making an ember application for creating an invoice. i am using ember component (textfield) to modify the fields using the keyboard, but since actions are not sending back to the relevant controller, i cannot save the records on focusOut or insertNewLine and nothing is happening. i am using :

```
Ember      : 1.1.2 
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.3 
Handlebars : 1.0.0 
jQuery     : 1.9.1
```

this is supposed to look like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7311507/embercomponent.png

The problem seems to lie within either the controller or the component, it seems i am missing something.

the console.log function gets called on the component, the sendAction call never works...

Thanks for the help.

## ItemsRoute

```
App.ItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
          // Render default outlet   
          this.render();
          // render extra outlets
          this.render("client", { outlet: "client", into: "application"});
      },
      model: function() {
        return this.store.find('item');
      }
    });
```

## ItemsController

```
App.ItemsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
      createItem: function () { // NEVER GETS CALLED FROM COMPONENT
        var title = "Nouvel élément"

        // Create the new Todo model
        var item = this.store.createRecord('item', {
          desc: title,
          qty: 1,
          price: 0
        });

        // Save the new model
        item.save();
      }
    },
    totalCount: function(){
        var total = 0;
        this.get('model').forEach(function(item){
            total += item.get('totalprice');
        });
        return total;
    }.property('@each.qty', '@each.price')
});
```

## ItemController

```
App.ItemController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        this.$().focus();
    },
    actions: {
        testAction: function(){ // NEVER GETS CALLED FROM COMPONENT
            console.log("controller recieved call for testAction");
        },
        saveItem: function(value) {
            this.get('model').save();

        },
        removeItem: function() {
            var item = this.get('model');
            item.deleteRecord();
            item.save();
          },
    },
    isHovering: false
});
```

## Items Template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="items">
      <!-- ...  -->

      <tbody>
      {{#each itemController="item"}}
        {{view App.ItemView }}
      {{/each}}
      </tbody>

      <!-- ... -->
  </script>
```

## ItemView template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="item">
    <td class="desc">{{edit-item value=desc}}</td>
    <td class="qty">{{edit-item-number value=qty }}</td>
    <td class="">{{edit-item-number step="25" value=price}}</td>
    <td class="totalprice">
      {{ totalprice }}
      <div class="delete-item" {{bindAttr class="isHovering"}} {{action "removeItem" on="click"}}>
        <i class="icon-trash"></i>
      </div>
    </td>
  </script>
```

## Views / Components

```
App.ItemView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: "item",
    tagName: "tr",

    mouseEnter: function(event) {
        this.get('controller').set('isHovering', true);
    },
    mouseLeave: function(event) {
        this.get('controller').set('isHovering', false);
    }
});

App.EditItem = Em.TextField.extend({
    becomeFocused: function() {
        this.$().focus();
    }.on('didInsertElement'),

    insertNewline: function(){
        console.log('Tried to insert a new line'); // WORKS
        this.triggerAction('createItem'); // DOESN'T WORK
    },

    focusOut: function(){
        console.log('Focused the Field Out') // WORKS
        this.triggerAction('testAction', this); // DOESN'T WORK
    }

});

App.EditItemNumber = App.EditItem.extend({
    becomeFocused: null,
    attributeBindings: ["min", "max", "step"],
    type: "number",
    min: "0"
});

Ember.Handlebars.helper('edit-item', App.EditItem);
Ember.Handlebars.helper('edit-item-number', App.EditItemNumber);
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should define where the action will be sent when defining a component in the template.

```
{{edit-item value=desc createItem='someactionoutside'}}
```

this is in case the action has a different name in different places (since this is a component, it could have different meanings in different locations).  It also avoids clashing actions/triggered actions.  Think of the idea of having two instances of a component, and each one should trigger a different action in the controller

```
{{edit-item value=desc createItem='createUser'}}
{{edit-item value=desc createItem='createShoppingCart'}}
```

in your case you can just write

```
{{edit-item value=desc createItem='createItem'}}
```

And inside your component you would call

```
this.sendAction('createItem', param1, param2, ....);
```

If you don't care about it being self contained like a component, you might want to just use a view and not a component.  You can register it as a helper and it'd look just as pretty.

```
Em.Handlebars.helper('edit-item', Em.View.extend({
  templateName: 'some_template',

  actions: function(){
   // etc etc
  } 

})); 

{{edit-item}}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this solved my problem, i understand the concept behind this (the components being self-contained), but it my case this introduces code repetition.

Comment: A view might be easier if you don't care about being self-contained

Comment: Also note the quotes in the template are **really** important.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the nice answer by @Kingpin2k you can also define your action's name within the component if it is always the same and you want to simplify the syntax of including your component. ie.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend(SchoolPlayerProspectMixin, {

    //Here we define an attribute for a string that will always be the same
    transitionToRoute: "transitionToRoute",

    somethingChanged: function(){
        console.log( "OMG something changed, lets look at a post about it!" );

        //Here we are passing our constant-attribute to the sendAction.
        self.sendAction('transitionToRoute', "post.show", post );

    }.observes('changableThing'),
});
```

In this example the component uses the parent controllers transitionToRoute method to change routes, even though the component may not be a button/link. For example, navigating on change of a component containing several select inputs, or just changing route from within a component in general.